# Что делать если нет дампа mysql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Перенёс базу данных с сервера в облако, загрузил на на новый сервер и понял, что надо было делать дамп, а доступа к тому сервера нет никакого, там база удалена.

При попытки сделать какой-нибудь SQL-запрос выкидывает ошибку:

> ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist in engine

Есть только файлы *.frm, *.idb и один файл db.opt

Не столько важны данные из таблиц, сколько их структура.

Можно ли как-то увидеть структуру таблицы?

Comment: https://dbsake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/frmdump.html

Comment: @andreymal помучался, поставил Bash, почекал документацию - сработало! Если хотите, можете написать решение к вопросу